# Routing old .php URLs to Lumen's clean URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect, lumen

I'm building a small app that needs to redirect old URLs to the newer and cleaner URLs that Lumen provides.

Basically I want to route and possibly giving it a 301 redirect.

```
/something.php?id=1 -> /somethings/1
```

The problem is this code doesn't seem to work:

```
$app->get('/something.php?id={id}', function ($id) {
    redirect()->route('somethings', ['id' => $id]);
});
```

This route is where I wanted to redirect this to:

```
$app->get('somethings/{id}', [
    'as' => 'somethings', 'uses' => 'SomeController@show'
]);
```

This is supposed to work, but I can't seem to manage it.

I would also go the .htaccess route if that's better.

Adding this snippet into the `public/.htaccess` file didn't seem to work either.

```
RewriteRule something\.php?id=(.+)$ somethings/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not very handy with rewrites, so there could be something wrong that I'm totally missing here.

Anyone wanna point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in Lumen itself, but it'll be faster if you use `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^something.php$ /somethings/%1 [R=301,L]
```

The above should be placed just below `RewriteEngine On`. In addition, you should know that a condition only applies to the rule that follows. So, If you want to check another URI and query string, you'll need to repeat the above for that.

If you'd prefer to use Lumen, you can add this to your routing config:

```
$app->get('something.php', function() use ($app) {

    $request = $app['request'];
    $param = 'id';
    if ($request->has($param)) {
        if (preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $request->input($param))) {
            return redirect()->route('somethings', ['id' => $request->input($param)]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wanted to go the htaccess route, but it simply doesn't work. I've inserted your snippet and tried various combinations, none affect the outcome. I still get `No input file specified`. Am I possibly putting it into the wrong `.htaccess` file? This is the one I'm editing: `public/.htaccess`

Comment: That appears to be a Homestead error. I'm not clued up on Homestead, however, and so won't be able to help you on that front. Perhaps someone else can jump in and try to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the value of `id` from the old URL, you can resolve `request` service inside the route and get the value of `id` from there. Like this :

```
$app->get('somethings.php',function() use ($app){
    dd($app['request']->id);
});

//localhost/somethings.php?id=1 ---> return "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the `return` keyword, It should be:

```
return redirect()->route('somethings', ['id' => $id]);
```

Instead of

```
redirect()->route('somethings', ['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I also tried doing a `dd('HERE')` inside the function and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Homestead, it runs nginx as the web server and not Apache. .htaccess is specific to Apache.